# Need to create required foreign key pointing to User, Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I need to create required field with foreign key pointing to User. Is this correct?

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

Comment: You should remove the `default=''` that makes no sense, but now it will indeed require a value for `created_by`.

Comment: Hello @J maria, By default ForeignKey is required.
```created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)```

If you want to make it null.

```created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need default in your created field. Everything else looks fine

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69683991/edit) to explain how/why the code solves the problem. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30153736)